# New document from document library using office client defaults to onedrive for save location

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-integration

Previously the Office client would default to the current document library for saving a new file, now it defaults to the users OneDrive.

Steps to reproduce.

- Document library on SharePoint site is configured to use Office client for new files.
- Click new word document from document library drop down menu.
- New document opens in Word client
- When clicking save the suggested save location is the users personal OneDrive. Previously the suggested save location was the document library. Now the user will have to manually browse to the document library.

This is tested in both SharePoint online and SharePoint 2016. Site is in intranet zone. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're not exactly giving us much to work with. Please provide more detail about how the new document is started and a screenshot of what you see when a new document is saved.

Comment: Would you please explain a bit more about “default”? Do you mean the menu under "Save" in Office client? If yes, that would depend on which version of Office you are using, but in most situation the default behavior. If that is not what you mean, please feel free to point it out.

Comment: I have clarified my question with more information. @Chelsea_MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the default behavior set by Office client that new files would be saved to cloud (OneDrive).

You can manually change the default location by clicking “**Set As Default Location**” under Context Menu. But it allows only one file location to set as default, dynamic (Recent) location cannot be set as default.

Reference: [Customize the save experience in Office.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-save-experience-in-office-786200a7-f5f2-4d26-a3ae-b78c60dd5d3b)

[image]

Comment: I think it makes more sense to save to the current location in this scenario, similar to when using the browser. But I'll mark this as the answer and hopefully it will be improved in the future.